# Packaging large folders NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have a swing application running perfectly fine on Linux. The application depends on third party libraries. Now I want to create an installation package of this application, for windows. I am using Launch4j and NSIS for this.

The third party libraries are in a folder(106MB size). When I am trying to create a package by running `makensis` command,it never completes (I have to abort it explicitly).

To resolve this, I thought of using ZipDll plugin of NSIS. But when I try to `zip` this third party library folder, I get warning `name not matched` for all the contents of the folder and this also goes on(infinite loop), never completes (again I have to forcefully abort it).

`.tar.gz` works fine but then ZipDll plugin is not able to extract from .tar.gz.

What should I look for in this case? 
Does NSIS restrict on the size of folders?
Why does zipping goes into infinite loop with that warning (I looked into many similar posts related to this warning, but nothing could resolve this)?
Is there any NSIS plugin which can extract from .tar.gz folder?
The third party library folder contains many sub-folders each having .sdf.gz files in it.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the compression or using zlip if you are currently using lzma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. The problem was with the directory structure. It had few soft links which linked to other computer and was trying to package everything there(infinite loop). 
I got it fixed. The problem was not with NSIS

Answer (score 1):

NSIS is restricted to 2 GB file size - the resulting setup (.exe file) have to be max. 2 GB large.

Your situation is strange, 106 MB is not a problem for NSIS.

Can you paste log from makensis output - what is happening when you have to abort setup creating?

Comment: When I run the `makensis` command I get log output as : `File: "file_name" [compress] no_of_bytes bytes`. for every file inside the folder. When I abort I get this : `Aborting on Ctrl+C...

Note: you may have one or two (large) stale temporary file(s)
left in your temporary directory (Generally this only happens on Windows 9x). `